# Total no. of possible new images after shuffling the pixel location , what will be the average Euclidean dist across all these possible new images?

Tags: image-processing, probability, euclidean-distance

Consider a 1000x1000 image I, where all pixels in the left half (first 500 columns) are white and those in the right half (last 500 columns) are black. A new image (Inew) of the same size is formed from I by shuffling the pixel locations. Let D denotes the Euclidean distance between I and Inew. What is the total number of possible Inew images? What is the average of D across all these possible Inew images?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is given that the image is of dimension 2000x2000 , so total pixel no is 4M ( here capital M means Million).So if we think the image in a latent space of 4M dimension it is a single vector here. Now out of those 2M is of value 0( becuase there are black,and assuming the value for black is zero)and remaining 2M are of value 1(they are white and so represented by 1). The image 'I' is,in our case, a standard image which have left half (first 1000 columns) are white and those in the right half (last 1000 columns) are black. Now if I want to shuffel(we are asuming only those suffles where pixels of different colour can interchange there places,i.e, there is no chance of interchanging two white pixels) the position of those 4M pixels then I will get (applying concept of theory of combinations) [4M!]/[2M! x 2M!] no of different images named 'Inew'. So 'Inew' is a **unique** set of vectors in 4M dimensional space. so the total number of possible I_new images is 4M!]/[2M! x 2M!]

Now I am asked to calculate the average distance of these 'Inew' vectors from the 'I' vector.

So, one can easily say that in 'Inew' there will be 2 special image vector ,one of them is same as 'I'(let's call it 'I_prime', and we will not exclude this one even if it is exactly same as 'I'),so having a minimum euclidean distance(as element wise the vector is same as 'I' the Euclidean distance is zero here) and the another one having exactly opposit(here opposite means in place of 1 there will be 0 and in place of zero there will be 1) values in each dimension to the vector having the minimum Euclidean distnace(in this case it is 4M) from 'I'. And the others ( [4M!]/[2M! x 2M!] - 2 ) vectors have distances in between these two distances.

Now, we will find how many possible combination can have distance,D=(2)^(1/2) (,i.e, having 2 pixel interchanged their values) , and this can be happened in [(2M)C(1)] many ways( here (n)C(2) means the no of way of choosing 2 distinct objects from n no of distinct objects ) . Similarly having distance,D=(4)^(1/2) can be happened in [(2M)C(2)] many ways and so on till we find the no of possible combinations of pixels of an Image of set 'Inew' having distance,D=(4M-2)^(1/2), and that can be done in [(2M)C(2M-1)] ways.

After that we can calculate total distance and devide it by total no of vectors ,we will get the average Euclidean distance.

Here we will take a simple example for an 2x2 image:
Here, I=[1,0,1,0] , a 4 dimensional vector.
I_new={ [1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1] }
total Euclidean distance =  ( d1 +d2 +d3 +d4 +d5 + d6 ) = (0+1.414+1.414+2+1.414+1.414) = 7.656
It can be calculated as
sum([0,1.414,2]*[1,4,1])     * is for point wise multiplication , and thi sis the algorithm we need
.:. average distance= 7.656/6= 1.276 units

The python code for the problem is given here with generalization.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

# we are using here images with same height and width. So, here image_dimension = n if image is of nxn dims.
# Total_vectors is a list of no of vectors having same Euclidean distances from 'I' vector.
# Total_distances is another list containing the total distance for group of vectors having same distance (accordance with the list 'Distances')
#      so, the length of these two lists are same.
def get_average_distance(image_dimension):
    no_of_pixels=int(image_dimension*image_dimension)
    m=np.int((no_of_pixels/2) + 1)
    Total_distances=[]
    Total_vectors=[]
    for i in range(m):
        vect=(math.comb(np.int(no_of_pixels/2),i))**2
        dist=round(np.sqrt(2*i), 1)
        app=round(vect * dist ,3)
        Total_distances.append(app)
        Total_vectors.append(vect)
    return round(sum(Total_distances)/sum(Total_vectors),3)
```

[Here a clear explanation with calculation is shown with example of an image of dimension.](https://github.com/mahendranandi/Nothing/blob/main/Question_2/Question_2_SUM_PROJ.ipynb) {https://github.com/mahendranandi/Nothing/blob/main/Question_2/Question_2_SUM_PROJ.ipynb }

As the calculation is too lengthy, we should find some other ways to optimize it.

If anything seems to be wrong please inform me. Suggestions are always welcome.

THANK YOU

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-a-math-formula-in-a-post